# process csv/json data in java servlets and javascript

Tags: javascript, json, servlets

I need an opinion on how to approach my problem. I have no idea on how to start and on how to implement which functions on which parts of the software. So this is what I want to do:

I have a Java servlet which creates a simple csv file:

```
name1, value1
name2, value2
```

etc.

This needs to be somehow converted to JSON data, so it can be displayed on a jsp page:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "value": "value1"
    },
    {
        "name": "name2",
        "value": "value2"
    }
]
```

Then the user will be redirected to the jsp page. Is it possible to send the whole JSON structure via request object to the jsp page? Or is it the easiest if all processing is done in javascript and only the path to the csv file is sent via request object?

I'm kind of lost on this, since I first started last week with programming of web applications. I'd just need a push in the right direction and then I should be able to figure out the rest on my own ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, look for a [CSV parser](http://google.com/search?q=java%20csv%20parser) which can turn a CSV file into a `List<Bean>` or `List<Map<K,V>>`.

Then, look for a [JSON parser](http://google.com/search?q=java%20json%20parser) which can turn a `List<Bean>` or `List<Map<K,V>>` into a JSON string.

Finally, just do the math and set the resulting JSON string as a request attribute which you print in JSP as if it's a JS variable, like so `<script>var data = ${data};</script>`.